# Search query with filtering in oracle database

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE (1 = 1 OR FIRST_NAME = 'renz')
    AND (1 = 1 OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%t%')
    AND (1 = 1 OR EMAIL = 'ASD')
    AND
    (CASE 
      WHEN ('06/20/2016'!='' AND '01/23/2017'!='')
        THEN HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('06/20/2016','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('01/23/2017','YYYYMMDD')
      WHEN ('06/20/2016'!='' AND '01/23/2017'=='')
        THEN HIRE_DATE >=TO_DATE('06/20/2016','YYYYMMDD')
      WHEN ('06/20/2016'=='' AND '01/23/2017'!='')
        THEN HIRE_DATE <=TO_DATE('01/23/2017','YYYYMMDD')
    END)
```

Im trying to create a search query that will search : firstname exactly match, lastname partial match, email exact match, data between from date and to date
 if both from and to are present it will return data between those date
 if from is the only present it will return data with date greater than from
 if to is the only present it will return data with date less than to date
How can i achieve this? The data for my filtering is from my jsp page pass to my DAO class

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE (1 = 1 OR FIRST_NAME = 'renz')
    AND (1 = 1 OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%t%')
    AND (1 = 1 OR EMAIL = 'ASD')
    AND HIRE_DATE BETWEEN NVL(TO_DATE(:FROM_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'), HIRE_DATE) 
                      AND NVL(TO_DATE(:TO_DT,'YYYYMMDD'), HIRE_DATE)
;
```

Comment: Sir the said date is user input from jsp how will i place it in :FROM_DT

Comment: :fron_dt is a place holder for a bind variable.  I suggest that you research how to use bind variables from JSP (I have not done it since about 2002, so I don't remember).  Also, if you use the literal date string instead of :from_dt, the approach (or similar) I suggested should still work.

Comment: I usually try out the ideas first in SQL*Plus or TOAD first to make sure the SQL syntax works as expected, then cut to code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees e
 WHERE e.first_name = NVL( :first_name, e.first_name )
   AND e.last_name LIKE NVL( :last_name, e.last_name )
   AND e.email = NVL( :email, e.email )
   AND e.hire_date BETWEEN NVL( :start_date, e.hire_date )
                       AND NVL( :end_date, e.hire_date )
```

The query can be executed using zero or more parameters.